# Problemas para renderizar main.js do Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Pessoal sou novato no Vue e estou precisando dar manutenção em um projeto.. o problema é o seguinte: tenho no main.js o esquema de rotas..

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});
```

page.vue

```
<span>{{ message }}</span>
```

Acontece que estou tentando exibir a "message" que está no data em um template externo.. que está no endereço de pastas "../pages/page.vue"; mais quando coloco {{ message }} me retorna o seguinte erro:

[Vue warn]: Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

Obrigado!

Comment: Não tem sentido você definir propriedades no main.js, a transferência de dados é feita através dos componentes vue, no main você deve renderizar seu componente central e gerenciar as biblioteca

Comment: Aqui tem um bom exemplo de métodos para transferir dados entre componentes https://codesandbox.io/s/mm58vw8px8

Comment: Blz vou ler aqui valeu man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você está tentando acessar uma propriedade do `data`, no caso a `message` que está em seu `main.js` em um componente `page.vue`.

Se for isto, isto não irá funcionar. Você deverá ter esta variável dentro do `data()` do componente `page.vue`. Verifique o exemplo abaixo:

**page.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span>{{ message }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'page',
  data () {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Outro jeito de fazer, é um jeito que eu particularmente não recomendo, mas você conseguirá acessar a variável `message` da instância do Vue com o `this.$root`. Verifique o exemplo abaixo:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.$root.message)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui como primeiro exemplo brother! vlw.. caso eu queira reutilizar o mesmo objeto na aplicação inteira eu preciso utilizar o conceito de storage.. como o Vuex, certo ?! Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada. Sim, o ideal seria utilizar o Vuex ou o Vue Stash, caso a aplicação for menor. Não é recomendado a utilização do `this.$root`, utilizando o `data` da instância do Vue, pelo menos na minha opinião.

Comment: Blz obrigado man!